# Unable to connect to SQL server instance ubuntu 18.04 via SSMS which worked peviously

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I am running SQL server on ubuntu 18.04 which I was able to connect to successfully via SSMS. But I am not able to connect anymore.
My first instinct was to check if the SQL server was running by executing

```
sudo systemctl status mssql-server
```

lo and behold the SQL server instance was active so I rebooted the entire server and ran the above command again and saw the following:

```
mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-10-16 16:49:17 UTC; 1min 13s ago
Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
Process: 1025 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 1025 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Oct 16 16:49:17 lamp-xxxxx systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 16 16:49:17 lamp-xxxxx systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 16 16:49:17 lamp-xxxxx systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart. 
Oct 16 16:49:17 lamp-xxxxx systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Oct 16 16:49:17 lamp-xxxxx systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
Oct 16 16:49:17 lamp-xxxxx systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 16 16:49:17 lamp-xxxxx systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 16 16:49:17 lamp-xxxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

I checked the logs at /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog and found this .

```
2019-10-14 13:52:56.16 spid51      CImageHelper::Init () Failed load of 
symbol file with path = /binn/;/BINN - Not enough storage is available to 
process this command.

2019-10-14 13:52:56.17 spid51      CImageHelper::Init () Failed load of 
symbol file with path = /binn/;/BINN - Not enough storage is available to process this command.

2019-10-14 13:52:56.19 spid51      Error: 19099, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2019-10-14 13:52:56.19 spid51      Trace ID '1' was stopped because of an error. Cause: 0x80070005(Access is denied.). Restart the trace after correcting the problem.
2019-10-14 13:52:56.20 spid51      Error: 17053, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2019-10-14 13:52:56.20 spid51      FCB::MakePreviousWritesDurable: Operating system error (null) encountered.
2019-10-14 13:52:56.21 spid51      Error: 9001, Severity: 21, State: 1.
2019-10-14 13:52:56.21 spid51      The log for database 'master' is not available. Check the operating system error log for related error messages. Resolve any errors and restart the database.
2019-10-14 13:52:56.24 spid51      Error: 9001, Severity: 21, State: 16.
```

I'm not an expert and don't know the next move to make.

Comment: Did you check your storage of your server? Got enough room free for sql to function?

Comment: its a freshly installed sql server instance. server actually has 2 gig ram. I have a similar sql server instance that runs well on another machine though that was ubuntu 16.04 and this is 18.04

Comment: I don't have any experience with SQL on linux, however this message : "Not enough storage is available to process this command." Made it sound like your disks are running out of space. Even if it's freshly installed, if your disks are full, sql can't do much.